# NFS + Kerberos: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: nfs, kerberos

I have NFS&Kerberos configured as described here: [How do I configure a Kerberos NFS server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7](http://linux.tutsgo.com/2016/09/how-do-i-configure-kerberos-nfs-server.html)

All diagnostics operations come fine, but when I try to mount my shares on the client side, I am getting following message:

```
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting kdc.example.com:/var/backup
```

Both server&client's IPs are in both /etc/hosts (server & client machines), in a first place after the IP. My configuration is:

/etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = kdc.example.com
  admin_server = kdc.example.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

/etc/exports:

```
/var/backup client.example.com(rw,sync,no_wdelay,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,sec=krb5)
/mnt/storage client.example.com(rw,sync,no_wdelay,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,sec=krb5)
```

/var/kerberos/krb5kdc:

```
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 88
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc_ports = 88
    admin_keytab = /etc/kadm5.keytab
    database_name = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/principal
    acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
    key_stash_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/stash
    max_life = 10h 0m 0s
    max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
    master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
    supported_enctypes = arcfour-hmac:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des:normal des:v4 des:norealm des:onlyrealm des:afs3
    default_principal_flags = +preauth
}
```

krb5kdc & kadmin services are up and running on the server.

/etc/fstab on client:

```
#NFS area
kdc.example.com:/var/backup                              /mnt/backup                   nfs4     rsize=65536,wsize=65536,nolock,hard,sec=krb5
kdc.example.com:/mnt/storage                             /mnt/storage                  nfs4     rsize=65536,wsize=65536,nolock,hard,sec=krb5
```

When I do:

```
mount -vv -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 kdc.example.com:/var/backup backup
```

I am getting message:

```
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Mon May 22 23:32:59 2017
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=95.85.33.75,clientaddr=192.168.0.2'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting kdc.example.com:/var/backup
```

First remark - why clientaddr is 192.168.0.2 but not client.example.com which is set in the both /etc/hosts? Anyways, the same message appears when I add clientaddr=client.example.com into the -o option of mount.

Second message is in the /var/log/krb5kdc.log of server:

```
CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: NOUSER@EXAMPLE.COM for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM, Client not found in Kerberos database
```

klist -k on server:

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 host/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 host/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 host/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 nfs/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 nfs/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 nfs/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

klist -k on client:

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 host/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 host/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 nfs/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 nfs/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 nfs/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

kadmin -p root/admin:

```
kadmin:  listprincs
K/M@EXAMPLE.COM
edrive@EXAMPLE.COM
host/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
host/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/changepw@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
nfs/client.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
nfs/kdc.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
```

So, what the issue is? Why I cannot mount my NFS share?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. According to this smal tutorial https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-use-kerberos-control-access-nfs-network-shares/
you should enable nfs-secure-server service in server side and nfs-secure service in client side.
This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue yesterday and this seems to occur because of missing principals on the KDC and rpc-gssd.service being stopped on the client.

On the KDC server, a tail -f /var/log/krb5kdc.log should be launched and missing principals if any should appear in the log when attempts of mounting the NFS share is being made from the client.

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo mount -o sec=krb5 server1:/knfs /knfs -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Feb 24 09:44:35 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=192.168.121.163,clientaddr=192.168.121.26'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=192.168.121.163,clientaddr=192.168.121.26'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=192.168.121.163'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
^C
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

In the log output the missing principal has been identified:

```
[vagrant@server1 ~]$ sudo tail -f /var/log/krb5kdc.log 
Feb 24 09:42:35 server1 krb5kdc[2870](info): TGS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.121.26: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0,  nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM for nfs/kerberos.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, Server not found in Kerberos database
Feb 24 09:42:35 server1 krb5kdc[2870](info): TGS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.121.26: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0,  nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM for nfs/kerberos.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, Server not found in Kerberos database
Feb 24 09:42:35 server1 krb5kdc[2870](info): TGS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.121.26: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0,  nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM for nfs/kerberos.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, Server not found in Kerberos database
Feb 24 09:42:35 server1 krb5kdc[2870](info): TGS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.121.26: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0,  nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM for nfs/kerberos.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, Server not found in Kerberos database
```

The missing principal needs to be added on the KDC and the client's key should be exported to the client {/etc/krb5.keytab}.

```
sudo kadmin.local -q "ktadd nfs/kerberos.example.com"
sudo kadmin.local -q "ktadd -k /tmp/krb5.keytab nfs/desktop1.example.com"
```

The keytab on the client side :

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo klist -ek
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1) 
   3 nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5) 
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

The permission denied should no longer be present but another warning should appear for wrong arguments.

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo mount -o sec=krb5 server1:/knfs /knfs -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Feb 24 09:07:32 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=192.168.121.54,clientaddr=192.168.121.195'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=192.168.121.54,clientaddr=192.168.121.195'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=192.168.121.54'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=192.168.121.54,clientaddr=192.168.121.195'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=192.168.121.54'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=192.168.121.54,clientaddr=192.168.121.195'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,addr=192.168.121.54'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
^C
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

After starting the service rpc-gssd.service, the error disappears and the NFS share was mounted correctly:

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo systemctl start rpc-gssd.service 
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo mount -o sec=krb5 server1:/knfs /knfs -v mount.nfs: 
timeout set for Sun Feb 24 09:07:47 2019 mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=192.168.121.54,clientaddr=192.168.121.195' 
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

Tickets were as follows:

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo klist -e
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:krb_ccache_kfAgj83
Default principal: nfs/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
01/01/70 00:00:00  01/01/70 00:00:00  Encrypted/Credentials/v1@X-GSSPROXY:
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is somewhat old, but if you're still looking for this, I've faced similar problem and got a solution myself, you can get this at my answer to my problem ["Fedora 26 NFS + Kerberos “Preauthentication failed” (mount lead to no permission)"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396943/fedora-26-nfs-kerberos-preauthentication-failed-mount-lead-to-no-permission), I'm pretty sure RHEL can follow those settings

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a RHEL 7 server in an environment where kerberos is managed by FreeIPA. A little bit of setup:

This environment is an AD / FreeIPA environment where FreeIPA (server `idm.nix.example.com`) has a two-way trust to the Windows DC, `dc.example.com`. Both Linux and Windows servers both live in the same subnet, `172.16.0.0/24`. As such, since MSAD was created first, when FreeIPA is configured no reverse zones are created dynamically for `nix.example.com` hosts. This is a known problem and is tracked via [this BugZilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1357429).

When running the mount command, I was getting the following error. There was no corresponding error on the NFS server:

```
[root@idm1 ~]# mount -v -o sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p -t nfs 172.16.0.9:/share /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Sep  8 21:58:01 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p,vers=4.1,addr=172.16.0.9,clientaddr=172.16.0.6'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p,vers=4.0,addr=172.16.0.9,clientaddr=172.16.0.6'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p,addr=172.16.0.9'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 172.16.0.9 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 172.16.0.9 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 172.16.0.9:/share
```

By change I happened to do `systemctl status rpc-gssd.service` and got the following error:

```
[root@idm1 ~]# systemctl status rpc-gssd.service
● rpc-gssd.service - RPC security service for NFS client and server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpc-gssd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-09-08 15:32:28 EDT; 6h ago
  Process: 28217 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.gssd $GSSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28218 (rpc.gssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpc-gssd.service
           └─28218 /usr/sbin/rpc.gssd

Sep 08 21:50:39 idm1.nix.example.com rpc.gssd[28218]: **ERROR: unable to resolve 172.16.0.9 to hostname: Name or service not known**
Sep 08 21:50:39 idm1.nix.example.com rpc.gssd[28218]: **ERROR: failed to parse nfs/clntf3/info**
```

Since this `NIX` environment doesn't have PTRs dynamically created, you either have to add the NFS server to `/etc/hosts` or create the relevant PTR record manually. You can verify this fixes the problem by adding the NFS server to `/etc/hosts`:

```
[root@idm1 ~]# echo "172.16.0.9 nfs.nix.example.com" >> /etc/hosts
[root@idm1 ~]# ls /mnt
hgfs
[root@idm1 ~]# mount -v -o sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p -t nfs 172.16.0.9:/share /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Sep  8 22:01:00 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p,vers=4.1,addr=172.16.0.9,clientaddr=172.16.0.6'
[root@idm1 ~]# ls /mnt
idm1  idm1-2
```

**TL;DR:** In an MSAD <-> IPA trust environment, make sure something is providing your PTR records for services like NFS since they aren't dynamically created.