# Fedora 26 NFS + Kerberos "Preauthentication failed" (mount lead to no permission)

Tags: fedora, nfs, kerberos

I'm having a hard time trying to setup `nfs` + `kerberos` at Fedora 26.

I've followed this tutorial:

[RHEL7: Use Kerberos to control access to NFS network shares | CertDepot](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-use-kerberos-control-access-nfs-network-shares/)

At the moment, pure NFS works fine, `kinit` alone works fine, but I still get 
 no permission while trying to mount and those errors at `/var/log/krb5kdc.log`.

```
krb5kdc[12560](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 16 23 25 26 20 19}) 192.168.0.13: NEEDED_PREAUTH: nfs/rbenedettin.local@LOCAL for krbtgt/LOCAL@LOCAL, Additional pre-authentication required                        
krb5kdc[12560](info): preauth (encrypted_timestamp) verify failure: Preauthentication failed                                                                                                                      
krb5kdc[12560](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 16 23 25 26 20 19}) 192.168.0.13: PREAUTH_FAILED: nfs/rbenedettin.local@LOCAL for krbtgt/LOCAL@LOCAL, Preauthentication failed
```

I want to use `zero-config`, I tried without it (editing `/etc/hosts`), but the problem persists, some other tutorials, point to `authconfig-gui` or `authconfig-tui` but Fedora 26 does not have it anymore. There is near no information on the web about recent Fedora releases and nfs + kerberos so I would really appreciate any light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### What Appears To Be The Problem
>
> The tutorial completely ignored many needed elements in fact (`sssd`, `pam`, etc), probably it is not the point of it as the focus appears to be RHEL exams. I'm still a little lost on all tools involved in this task as I'm not a sysadmin (a lot of question for another moment), but I've managed to get it working. Thanks to `freeIPA` most.
>
> I will try to put what I did here. I expect it gives some light on how to get a kerberized  NFS environment in Fedora 26 and maybe 25 plus. **please, anyone that finds any inadequate procedure please, correct it.** It only touches a zero-conf without SELinux environment, so anywone that can close the gaps is welcome to correct it.
>
> #### If You Already Did A Lot Of Mess
>
> If you were brave enough to try a ton of things, even put an OpenLDAP server up without results, remove it all, remove both `Kerberos` and `OpenLDAP`, delete configurations files and caches in `/etc` and `/var/lib/`, you can maintain your NFS server if you already got it working without Kerberos. If you played with `sssd` delete /etc/sssd and reinstall the package.

---

## How to get NFS + Kerberos in fedora 26

In a short description you will need to:

1. Hostname (**read observations**)
2. NFS server working.
3. Install freeIPA
4. Configure IPA + Kerberos + NFS
5. Observations

### Hostname

> Before continuing please read observations at the end of the answer, related with hostname.

As stated, I wanted a `zero-conf` setup. I named my machines and enabled/unmasked `avahi` service. If you have a vanilla Fedora installation Avahi should be on.

You can get or change the hostname with `hostnamectl`.

```
$ hostnamectl set-hostname "myhostname"
```

Thanks to `avahi`, all your local network will be over **local** domain, you will get your machines addressed like **yourhostname.local**. We will continue the setup with two machines:

**server.local** -> the server

**client.local** -> the client

`Kerberos`(freeIPA server) could be on a third machine, but for simplicity, both `freeIPA` and `NFS` will be served by one machine.

### NFS server

- #### Server Side

I will take as if you pretend to use NFSv4, so it only need this:

```
$ dnf install  nfs-utils

$ systemctl enable nfs-server
$ systemctl start nfs-server

$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Edit exports in `/etc/exports`:

```
# if using "sec=krb5p" your will need Kerberos, remove it for tests
/path/to/exported/dir client.local(rw,sync,sec=krb5p)
```

Export the directory:

```
$ exportfs -avr
$ systemctl restart nfs-server
```

- #### Client Side

Install needed package:

```
$ dnf install nfs-utils
```

You can test it with:

```
$ mount -t nfs server.local:/path/to/exported/dir /path/to/local/dir
```

### Install FreeIPA

- #### Server Side

Install `freeipa-server` and give pointed answers:

```
$ dnf install freeipa-server
$ ipa-server-install
...
Do you want to configure integrated DNS (BIND)? [no]: **no**
...
Server host name [server.local]: **press enter**    
...
Please confirm the domain name [local]: **press enter**
...
Please provide a realm name [LOCAL]: **press enter**
...
Directory Manager password: *******
Password (confirm): *******
...
IPA admin password: *******
Password (confirm): *******
...
Continue to configure the system with these values? [no]: **yes**
```

open needed firewall ports:

```
$ firewall-cmd --add-service={freeipa-ldap,freeipa-ldaps} --permanent 
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

- #### Client Side

Install `freeipa-client` and give pointed answers:

```
$ dnf install freeipa-client
$ ipa-client-install --server=serve.local --domain LOCAL
... 
Proceed with fixed values and no DNS discovery? [no]: **yes**
...
Continue to configure the system with these values? [no]: **yes**
...
User authorized to enroll computers: **admin**
...
Password for admin@SERVER.LOCAL: ******
```

### Configure IPA + Kerberos + NFS

At this point you will have an operational kerberos server and client, I will pretend that you have only a user named **user** at server and client.

- #### Server Side

We must authenticate as admin principal:

```
$ kinit admin
Password for admin@SERVER.LOCAL: *****
```

You can confirm you're authenticated with `klist`:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:krb_ccache_######       
Default principal: admin@LOCAL                            

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal    
17-10-2017 20:41:20  18-10-2017 20:41:17  krbtgt/LOCAL@LOCAL
```

Now we can add user principal, I advise you to use the same name and password of your Unix user:

```
$ ipa user-add user --email=user@yourmail.com --first=User --last="Foo" --password
password: ******
```

Add the service principal for `NFS`:

```
# --force is needed otherwise will complain about DNS record missing
$ ipa service-add nfs/server.local --force
```

get host and service keys:

```
$ ipa-getkeytab -s server.local -p host/server.local -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /etc/krb5.keytab

$ ipa-getkeytab -s server.local -p nfs/server.local -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /etc/krb5.keytab
```

- #### Client Side

  As at server side, authenticate as admin and add client host:

  $ kinit admin
  Password for admin@SERVER.LOCAL: *****

  $ ipa-getkeytab -s server.local -p host/client.local -k /etc/krb5.keytab
  Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /etc/krb5.keytab

Don't forget to add `sec=krb5p` to `/etc/export` at the server after configuring freeIPA and all the rest. Restart the server and client or restart `NFS` and `IPA` services. At this point, you will be able to mount the remote folder at the client.

```
$ mount -v -t nfs -o sec=krb5p server.local:/path/to/exported/dir /path/to/local/dir
```

### Observations

#### Zero-config setup not working well...

unfortunately, FreeIPA appears to be strongly dependent on `BIND`, a DNS server, a shame as it is too much for home use and can impose performance burden on low-end devices. The simples solution is not using `dhcp`, setting static IPs on all machines and define aliases in `/etc/hosts´:

```
x.x.x.x server.local server      
y.y.y.y client.local client
```

#### Why not configure pam so I get Kerberos Authentication at Login?

by what we can see [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=737048) freeipa, if using `sssd` don't need `authconfig --enablekrb5 --update`.

#### Partition Mounts But While accessing directory get "no permission" and an empty folder

Your user probably need access to its principal key (only root has access to `/etc/krb5.keytab`), according to `krb5.conf` man page, `sssd` default place for users `keytab` is `/var/kerberos/krb5/user/%{UID}/client.keytab` where %{UID} is the user id of the user.

```
$ ipa-getkeytab -s server.local -p user -k /var/kerberos/krb5/user/%{UID}/client.keytab --password
password: ******
Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /var/kerberos/krb5/user/%{UID}/client.keytab
```

Use the same password of unix user, we could have used -r, but it is nor recommended and actually need extra commands to be possible to retrive the existing keys (from when we have added the user) from server.

#### Chrony or NTP???

I'm not sure if freeIPA can work well with `chrony`, newer versions may need `--force-ntpd` to supplant `chrony` with `NTP`